# Remove All onclick Events for an Element

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

```
var links = document.body.querySelectorAll("p.sourcelinks a.individual_source_link");
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
{
    links[i].onclick = null;
}
```

Is my current code, however it doesn't remove the onclick events. I have no idea what they will be since this is a greasemonkey script.

Comment: "Is my current code (what) , however it doesn't remove the onclick events." !!!

Comment: "It is my current code, ..." I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code only deals with events added by element.onclick case.  What about events added with addEventListener (for standards compliant browsers) and attachEvent (for IE)?

You need to use removeEventListener and detachEvent to remove events as well as setting .onclick to null.  Then all your bases will be covered.

Comment: This is a Greasemonkey question. IE and `detachEvent` do not apply.

Answer (score 6):

This article would probably be useful:

[http://www.computerhowtoguy.com/how-to-use-the-jquery-unbind-method-on-all-child-elements/](https://web.archive.org/web/20180823093658/http://www.computerhowtoguy.com/how-to-use-the-jquery-unbind-method-on-all-child-elements/)

One part in particular is a recursive function that removes all click events. Remember that jQuery will remove click events IF the click event was created using jQuery. the function given in the article will remove both those created with jQuery and those that were not. The function given is this:

```
function RecursiveUnbind($jElement) {
    // remove this element's and all of its children's click events
    $jElement.unbind();
    $jElement.removeAttr('onclick');
    $jElement.children().each(function () {
        RecursiveUnbind($(this));
    });
}
```

You would call the function like this:

```
RecursiveUnbind($('#container'));
```

That function takes a jQuery object parameter, but you could easily change it up to pass a string as the name of the ID for the element, or however you think is best.

While this only addresses click events you could easily modify it to handle others or all.

Comment: Your link is dead. I could not understand if the `RecursiveUnbind` code you added here will remove JQuery and NonJQuery elements or just the JQuery ones. If not, can you add the code which removes both JQuery and NonJQuery ones?

Answer (score 1):

That code doesn't work [because of GM's sandbox.  `links` is in an XPCNativeWrapper](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.234%3a_Custom_Properties).

To get around this use `setAttribute()`, like so:

```
var links = document.body.querySelectorAll("p.sourcelinks a.individual_source_link");
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
{
    links[i].setAttribute ("onclick", null);
}
```

Note that click handlers that are set other ways, will need to be cleared other ways (`removeEventListener()`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.from(document.all).forEach(el=>{
el.onselectstart=null
el.oncontextmenu=null
document.oncontextmenu=null
})
```

here is the solution
Right click and select event bypassed

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have either an `href` or a JavaScript function being called on the `onClick` for an `<a>` link.

You can remove either of these by removing the `href` tag, the `onClick` event or in this case both of them.

```
    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
    {

        links[i].href='#';
        links[i].onclick = '';
    }
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work for http://tv.blinkx.com/show/penn-teller-bullshit/Uy5MaFV5qcfgsDINw-hR0_Xfvuo#s3e6

Comment: @Steven - what are trying to disable? The elements on that page don't match the criteria in your question.